# Test different invocation pattern

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, functional-testing, python-importlib, cookiecutter

I want to test how a project generated by [cookiecutter](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter) behave with multiple invocation patterns.

Given the following generated project

```
proj/
    proj/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
```

Content of `__init__.py`:

```
def func():
    pass
```

Content of `__main__.py`:

```
from proj import func

def main():
    func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(I have read about issues of `__main__.__spec__`, this is not what this question is about.  In fact, I would like to test-drive -TDD- my work arounds of these issues)

Now I write tests in which the generated project structure and location is known (available via pytest fixtures, for instance)

```
test_run_proj_script():
    """Test behavior of ``python3 ./proj``"""
    pass # how to run this?

test_run_proj_module():
    """Test behavior of ``python3 -m ./proj``"""
    pass # how to run this?
```

Bonus: inject values for `sys.argv` ?